# Java - continuously check if the new value in an arraylist is unique

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jsp, arraylist

I have an arraylist full of usernames that I am hoping to display on a webpage. At the moment my arraylist looks like this:

[user=johndoe, user=sampletest, user=johndoe, user=myusername, user=myusername, user=terryh, user=terryh, user=johndoe]

How do I get my arraylist to look like this:

[user=johndoe, user=sampletest, user=myusername, user=terryh]

I've tried other answers but none of them seem to work for me

Comment: Use a `Set`. Not a `List`.

Comment: Use a data structure that makes this easier, e.g. a `Map<String, User>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider This recommendation is correct. If you are 100% dead set on using a List, then you must call `contains(element)` before adding, but this is expensive O(n) operation where `n` is the size of your list. A `Set` will handle this automatically in constant time.

Comment: "I've tried other answers but none of them seem to work for me" - then they are being used out of context and/or incorrectly. It would be beneficial to describe the *actual* problem/symptoms encountered (preferably with real code), not merely the task.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to simply stop using `ArrayList` and rather, use a `Set`. Since all of the element **are** users, you can discard `user=` before each element, but I'll keep it in the following code for continuity.

```
Set<String> userSet = new LinkedHashSet();
```

For example, in the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<String> userSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    userSet.add("user=johndoe");
    userSet.add("user=sampletest");
    userSet.add("user=johndoe");
    userSet.add("user=myusername");
    userSet.add("user=myusername");
    userSet.add("user=terryh");
    userSet.add("user=terryh");
    userSet.add("user=johndoe");

    for (String user : userSet) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

The output is just:

```
user=johndoe
user=sampletest
user=myusername
user=terryh
```